# Deserializing nested JSON, or simply pass it forward in Go

Tags: json, postgresql, go, go-gorm

Building a basic API with Go, I've got JSON stored in a JSON field in a postgres table, along with some other (plain) datatypes. Using my model, I'm simply trying to fetch a row from the database and pass it forward as JSON.

Using [GORM](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm) to deserialize the data into a struct, most of the mapping happens seamlessly, except for the JSON, which depending on selected datatype either renders as a bytearray or string.

Here are the models (Updated):

```
type Item struct {
    --snip--
    Stats []ItemInfo `gorm:"column:stats" json:"stats" sql:"json"`
    --snip--
}

type ItemInfo struct {
    Stat        string      `json:"stat"`
    Amount      int         `json:"amount"`
}
```

With the typical JSON looking like this (from the DB):

```
[{"stat": "Multistrike", "amount": 193}, {"stat": "Crit", "amount": 145}, 
 {"stat": "Agility", "amount": 254}, {"stat": "Stamina", "amount": 381}]
```

So the idea is that I simply want to pass this data on, not alter it, or deserialize it to a Go struct or anything. The controller/route follows:

```
func GetItem(c *gin.Context) {
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))

    // Convert Parameter to int, for db query
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Get the DB context
    db, ok := c.MustGet("databaseConnection").(gorm.DB)
    if !ok {
        // Do something
    }

    // Hold the structified item here.
    var returnedItem models.Item

    // Get the db row
    db.Where(&models.Item{ItemID: id}).First(&returnedItem)

    if c.Bind(&returnedItem) == nil {

        // Respond with the struct as json
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, returnedItem)
    }
}
```

Which responds with the following JSON (with stats as json.RawMessage):

```
{

    "context": "raid-finder",
    "stats": "W3sic3RhdCI6ICJWZXJzYXRpbGl0eSIsICJhbW91bnQiOiA0NX0sIHsic3RhdCI6ICJDcml0IiwgImFtb3VudCI6IDEwMH0sIHsic3RhdCI6ICJBZ2lsaXR5IiwgImFtb3VudCI6IDEwOX0sIHsic3RhdCI6ICJTdGFtaW5hIiwgImFtb3VudCI6IDE2M31d",
}
```

Or alternatively (with stats as string):

```
{
    "context": "raid-finder",
    "stats": "[{\"stat\": \"Versatility\", \"amount\": 45}, {\"stat\": \"Crit\", \"amount\": 100}, {\"stat\": \"Agility\", \"amount\": 109}, {\"stat\": \"Stamina\", \"amount\": 163}]",
}
```

What options do I have to simply pass this on, so far I've unsuccessfully attempted to map the JSON to a struct (which becomes difficult because of the dynamic data, and the reason I chose JSON to start with)?

I realize there's some magic going on from [gin-gonic](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), with c.JSON automatically(?) marshalling all of the data from the struct to JSON, but hoping there's some way to avoid marshalling the json data?

When ran with the ItemInfo substruct, it panics with the following error:

```
2016/01/07 08:21:08 Panic recovery -> reflect.Set: value of type []uint8 is not assignable to type []models.ItemInfo
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:423 (0x42a929)
        gopanic: reflectcall(nil, unsafe.Pointer(d.fn), deferArgs(d), uint32(d.siz), uint32(d.siz))
/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:2158 (0x5492ce)
        Value.assignTo: panic(context + ": value of type " + v.typ.String() + " is not assignable to type " + dst.String())
/usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1327 (0x546195)
```

EDIT: Updated code:

Comment: Might supply a complete answer later but my suggestion is fairly simple, add an extra field to your type to represent the json as a `[]byte`, let GORM unmarshal into that. After that use `encoding/json` to unmarshal the `[]byte` into the target struct.

Comment: I feel bad cause I missed your comment, and it turned out to be a super easy solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was easiest to just provide an additional property in the Item struct for GORM to unmarshal into []byte and then unmarshal the byte array as the sub-struct:

```
// Item is a thing..
type Item 
    Stats           []byte    `gorm:"column:stats"  json:"stats"`
    StatsList       []ItemInfo `json:"iteminfo"`
}
```

And unmarshal it like this:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(returnedItem.Stats, &returnedItem.StatsList)
```

Thanks to @evanmcdonnal for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Make a sub struct like `itemInfo` or something like:

```
type itemInfo struct {
    Stat string `json:"stat"`
    Crit int    `json:"crit"`
}
```

Then in your `Item` struct make

```
type Item struct {
    --snip--
    Context string `gorm:"column:context" json:"context"`
    Stats []itemInfo `gorm:"column:stats" json:"stats" sql:"json"`
    --snip--
}
```

Then when you unmarshal it should go just fine into item info!

Also I'm assuming you're using blizzards API, I have made a wrapper already you can view it here: https://github.com/Gacnt/Go-WoW-API to see how I have done it, but it's completely unfinished I only implemented the parts I needed when I was working on something.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  

I've set up a sub struct like your example, which unfortunately results in panic when fetching the row with the ORM, with the following message:  
  
`2016/01/06 17:20:35 Panic recovery -> reflect.Set: value of type []uint8 is not assignable to type []models.ItemInfo`   

I tried playing around with the datatype in model.ItemInfo, shifting between int/strings, with no real luck.

Comment: @PerFröjd Can you put your code into your question so I can see it?

Comment: Updated question with new structs and the exception